# Итальянская паста

Tags: значение-слов, семантика

Сейчас часто можно увидеть в меню ресторанов и кафе различные пасты, а что это такое? Блюдо, разновидность макарон или просто "вермишель с понтами"?

Comment: Тут бы конечно очень пригодилось бы мнение @natasha, но она к сожалению, уже давно не появлялась.

Comment: "Паста" вполне может подаваться безо всякого соуса, только под оливковым маслом, например. Кстати, спагетти - тоже "паста". И еще, в итальянском языке широко используется слово "maccheroni" (макароны)- вид трубчатой (как правило) короткой пасты (здесь вообще очень интересно происхождение самого слова, вроде как, от византийского  μακαρώνεια), а также "vermiccelli" (вермишель) - вид длинной пасты с круглым сечением более крупного диаметра, нежели спагетти.

Comment: >Кстати, спагетти - тоже "паста".   
  
Мы это обсуждали. 
Смотря что называть спагетти - и пастой. 
Если как предлагалось, паста - изделия только из трведых сортов пшеницы, то нет. Ибо спагетти (в России) вполне могут быть изготовлены из мягких сортов.  
   
>"vermiccelli"   
  
Это из французского. Не обсуждается.

Comment: В Италии спагетти изготавливаются также из мягких сортов пшеницы и продолжают называться "пастой".

Comment: А, ну тогда это по крайней мере непротиворечиво. 
Хотя судя по Википедии и некоторым другим источникам, мягкие сорта пшеницы в европе давно не используются иначе как в традиционных кондитерских рецептах...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Марк Из, спасибо, что вспомнили, всегда приятно)) Из интересующих значений "пасты" ит. словарь дает следующие: 1. Блюдо, приготовленное на основе теста, замешанного из муки из твердых сортов пшеницы на воде, различной формы нарезки и сваренного на воде или бульоне. 2. Маленькие кондитерские изделия (пироженные)

Answer (score 8):

Паста - это и макаронные изделия из твердых сортов пшеницы (любой формы и размеров), и блюда из этих изделий с различными соусами.

Answer (score 5):

Паста - итальянское название макаронных блюд "с наполнителем".
Чтобы не морочить голову: все, что не спагетти - почти все паста.

Ни "макароны", ни "вермишель" в итальянском не используется. 
Первое - чисто русское название, образованное от какого-то полузабытого названия дешевых спагетти, второе - из французской кухни, "заправка" для бульонов и т. п., в отличие от русской (и не только) лапши отвариваемая отдельно от самого блюда - и добавляемая уже в готовую жидкость после снятия с огня.
Так что просто "с понтами" - это да, но не вермишель, а мелкие макаронные изделия.

//------------------

С помощью Ларf вроде как установил, что по-итальянски pasta - это вообще всякие макаронные изделия... 
Но я по-прежнему сомневаюсь, что в русских заведениях, заказав "любую пасту", можно получить спагетти. Повторюсь, макароны - это не моя стихия, я и раньше был больше по азиатской кухне, а сейчас вообще давно нигде не бывал...

Comment: Спагетти- самый популярный в России вид пасты.

Comment: >Спагетти- самый популярный в России вид пасты.  
  
Насколько знаю, в России спагетти не принято называть пастой. 
Может, ситуация изменилась. Я сужу по концу девяностых когда работал у "Ростика". С тех пор по подобным заведениям не хожу.

А если вопрос в том, различают ли их в Италии - то тут можно спорить. Я не встречал на итальянском фраз подобных той, что есть в английской Вики, где действительно утверждается, что спагетти - вид пасты.  
Хотя да... 
"Spaghetti, tipo di pasta lunga;" ну что ж, будем знать...
Тогща получается, что паста - вообще любые макаронные издения? 
.

Comment: Любые из твердых сортов пшеницы.

Comment: А где Вы нашли это определение -и почему так настаиваете на твердых сортах?!

Comment: (+) 
Тут еще такая штука. В Италии мягкие сорта пшеницы просто не используются для привычных изделий (кроме, кажется, некоторых сортов кондитерских изделий). Но в России вполне можно найти пачку "Спагетти из мягких сортов пшеницы". После этого совокупное утверждение "спагетти - это паста, а паста это то что из твердых сортов" становится весьма сомнительным.

Answer (score 3):

По-моему все просто, паста - это тесто, происходит от  от итал. pasta «тесто, пирог». Даже в словаре Ожегова написано: "паста -  однородная смесь в виде тестообразной массы". Можно сказать, это разновидность теста, используемая для изготовление макаронных изделий.

Answer (score 2):

Паста - это  тесто, друзья. Все изделия из теста - паста: макаронные изделия (пшеничная, яичная, соевая и др. мука), пирожки и булочки. ПАСТА! Первое блюдо в итальянской кухне, превреднейшая превычка (в том смысле, что, подсев на нее с рождения, день без пасты будет сыр и убог).
Источник: живу я тут, и ем тоже здесь )))

Comment: привычка ))), ссори